# Apps don't accept that Mock Location is allowed

Tags: android, mocking, location, maps, spoof

I am using a LG G3 and I allowed Mock Locations in the Developer Options already. Yesterday I used the App "Mock Locations" to fake my Location and it worked fine but somehow today it tells me that I need to check the option "Mock Location" in developer options. But they are checked. And other apps do the same thing and I cant use them anymore. 
I also  tried to set the App as a Systemapp but that didn't help as well.

Someone knows how to help?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your manifest the permission is defined

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Also check in your developer options your app is selected for using the mock locations